# Cannot pass parameter by reference PHP prepared statement problem

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to make a query with a prepared statement to retrieve some information and make another query with the information that was received from the first query, but i am receiving the error:

```
Cannot pass parameter by reference
```

is there a way around this?

this is my code:

```
$DBH = getDBH();
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT small FROM info WHERE user = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$userid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($small);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO method(small) VALUES(?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$small);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: can you post the output of `var_dump($small)` after the first `$stmt->close();`

Comment: wen i dump it, it shows that the correct value is stored in the variable.

Comment: Its just dumping the variable stored. Its just "test" right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i may have got it to work by adding

```
return $small;
```

after

```
$stmt->fetch();
```

although i have not had time to test it with any actual values, I am not recieving any errors, but i am unsure if the code stops at

```
return $small;
```

or if everything continues to execute, i may be able to just rewrite it into a function and return the value.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Never mind the below! I was thinking of PDO**

---

Try changing the following lines:

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT small FROM info WHERE user = :s");
```

and

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO method(small) VALUES(:s)");
```

It's because you're trying to bind a nonexistent parameter. If you want to use question marks, you have to find it like so If I remember correctly.

```
$stmt->bind_param(0,$userid);
```